# Orchard CMS search index module does not index all of my documents

Tags: lucene, orchardcms

after i made some changes to some documents from the dashboard, they were not displayed as results of my back-end search, i update the "search index" and the same result, so i "Rebuild the search index". Now after a few minutes the search index contains almost all of my documents(not all) so the search does not match some content.
Anybody knows why? please help and thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the content type editor and make sure you configured your type to be indexed. It's a checkbox in there.

Comment: It's already checked, in fact, i can find the same type of content types in the search, but some others dont, only if i navigate through content items tab i can find them, but with more than 1000 items it's very tedious.
Thanks, i appreciate your answer.